# Change python object functions

Tags: python, function, class, object

I've seen somewhere that there was a way to change some object functions in python

```
def decorable(cls):
    cls.__lshift__ = lambda objet, fonction: fonction(objet)
    return cls
```

I wondered if you could do things like in ruby, with the :

```
number.times
```

Can we actually change some predefined classes by applying the function above to the class int for example? If so, any ideas how I could manage to do it? And could you link me the doc of python showing every function (like **lshift**) that can be changed?

Comment: EVERY function in python can be changed. (There are a few exceptions with built-in classes and functions but other than that the rule holds true)

Comment: um... when would you ever want to write `x >> func` instead of `func(x)`? And have you tried it? you can add or remove arbitrary attributes on the class any time after it's construction (or variables in the class block before it's creation)

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily not - 
as a rule, Python types defined in native code -in CPython can't be monkey patched to have new methods. Although there are means to do that with direct memory access and changing the C object structures, using CPython - that is not considered "clever", "beautiful", much less usable. (check https://github.com/clarete/forbiddenfruit)

That said, for class hierarchies you define on your own packages, that pretty much works - any magic "dunder" method that is set changes the behavior for all objects of that class, in all the process.

So, you can't do that to Python's "int" - but you can have a

```
class MyInt(int):
    pass

a = MyInt(10)

MyInt.__rshift__ = lambda self, other: MyInt(str(self) + str(other))

print(a >> 20)
```

Will result in `1020` being printed.

The Python document thta tells about all the magic methods taht are used by the language is the Data Model:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html